# Simple Google App Engine Datastore operation taking too long: causing DeadlineExceededException/DatastoreTimeoutException

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a fairly simple App Engine Java app that has Accounts, Orders and OrderItems - nothing crazy.

Just in the last 12 hours I have started getting exceptions thrown out of some fairly straight forward code that adds orders to accounts and then saves them.

I created a trivial testing servlet to replicate the issue, it looks like this:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
    throws IOException {

        String key = req.getParameter("key");

        PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
        Account account = pm.getObjectById(Account.class, KeyFactory.stringToKey(key));

        Order order = new Order();
        order.setExternalOrderID("ASHLEY-TESTING");

        Item item = new Item();
        item.setSku("ASHLEY-WIDGET-A");
        item.setQuantity(2);
        Item item2 = new Item();
        item2.setSku("ASHLEY-WIDGET-B");
        item2.setQuantity(2);

        order.addItem(item);
        order.addItem(item2);

        account.addOrder(order);
        order.setAccount(account);
        pm.makePersistent(order);
        pm.close();
    }

addOrder is implemented as a pretty standard lazy init:

    public void addOrder(Order order) {
        if (getOrders() == null) {
            setOrders(new ArrayList<Order>());
        }
        getOrders().add(order);
    }

The relevant parts of the entities:

@PersistenceCapable

public class Account {

//...

@Persistent(mappedBy="account")
@javax.jdo.annotations.Order(extensions = @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="list-ordering", value="orderDate desc"))
private List<Order> orders;

//...

}

and the Order has an account field:

    @Persistent
    private Account account;
```

This code is failing on the `account.addOrder()` line. if it is run directly in the browser it fails with DeadlineExceededException (after 30s) and if I enqueue it to run via a task queue it fails with DatastoreTimeoutException after a minute or two. It uses a truck load of CPU time in the process.

I would estimate that the Account would have fewer than 2000 Orders children under it, each Order with 1-3 OrderItem children.

My question is, why would this all of a sudden start failing it has worked to add the 1000's of orders already in there. And have I missed something vital? do I need to add indexes? could the data store really be this slow? Am I abusing it, should I not have children relationships with this many children - perhaps a set of keys would be a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

In one of google app engine slide, it mentioned that for the list property, datastore performance will be bad while the item number larger than "500". This slide is very old, I am not sure the limitation is still the same now, but that may be the problem for your case. And it makes sense to not store too many items in list property. In that slide, it suggest user to use an extend class for this situation. For example:

```
class Orders:
     Account account    // the account these order belong to.
     List<Order> orders // the orders, limit to 500 items
```

if you have more than 500 orders, just add another Orders instance.

Answer (score 0):

I have stopped using getOrders() in favor of the Query interface like this:

```
    Query query = pm.newQuery(Order.class);
    query.setFilter("account == accountKey");
    query.declareParameters(Key.class.getName() + " accountKey");
    query.setOrdering("orderDate desc");
    query.setRange(0, numOrders);
```

And for adding Orders to accounts, I simply set the parent property on a new Order and persist it, GAE handles creating the key and associates it to the parent.

```
            order.setAccount(account);
            pm.makePersistent(order);
```

I got some tips from the GAE/J Group here:
http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/6011d08025398254#

Also, lucemia's suggestion would work, but trickier to manage the code I think.